# Python PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-3.12

I have code:

```
import eel
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import urllib.request
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import os
import pathlib
import webbrowser
import ssl
import shutil

path = "web"
os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)

eel.init('web')

@eel.expose
def search(query):
    API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxx"
    CSE_ID = "xxxxxxxx"

    service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=API_KEY)
    response = service.cse().list(q=query, cx=CSE_ID).execute()

    if "items" in response and response["items"]:
        first_result = response["items"][0]

        url = first_result.get("formattedUrl", "")

        class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
            def __init__(self):
                super().__init__()
                self.urls = []

            def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
                if tag in ["script", "link", "img"]:
                    for attr in attrs:
                        if attr[0] in ["src", "href"]:
                            self.urls.append(attr[1])

        ctx = ssl._create_unverified_context()
        res = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx)
        if res.code == 200:
            html = res.read().decode("utf-8")

            parser = MyHTMLParser()
            parser.feed(html)
            urls = parser.urls

            html_path = pathlib.Path(path) / pathlib.Path(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path).name
            with open(html_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                f.write(html)

            for url in urls:
                if url.startswith("http"):
                    file_url = url
                else:
                    file_url = urllib.request.urljoin(res.url, url)

                file_path = pathlib.Path(path) / pathlib.Path(urllib.parse.unquote(urllib.parse.urlparse(file_url).path)).name
                try:
                    urllib.request.urlretrieve(file_url, file_path)
                except:
                    print(f"Neuspešno preuzimanje fajla: {file_url}")

            return html_path
        else:
            return None
    else:
        return None

input = input(">>> ")
html_path = search(input)
webbrowser.open(str(html_path), new=2)

shutil.rmtree('web')
```

This is my error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\Desktop\xxxxxxxxxxxx.py", line 72, in <module>
    html_path = search(input)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\Desktop\xxxxxxxx.py", line 50, in search
    with open(html_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'web'
```

I have Windows 10 and Python 3.12, I tried to run the program with administrator privileges but it didn't work. I also checked to see if there is any program that currently has the directory open but there isn't one. And I checked if I have write privileges, and I have.

Comment: My guess is that `pathlib.Path(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path).name` is an empty string. This means that you are trying to write to a directory as if it were a file. Can you verify the full path of the file you are attempting to write?

Comment: Upon further inspection, my above suggestion should raise an `IsADirectoryError` rather than a permissions error. Furthermore, the `PermissionError` is a subclass of `OSError`, which is caught by `makedirs` with `exist_ok=True`. Are you sure you are creating this `web` directory in the place you expect?

Comment: Does `html_path = "this"` without any nesting work?

Comment: C.Nivs, thank you, your pathlib comment is very usefull.